# Basic HTTP authentication with the Heroku Platform API

Tags: authentication, heroku

The [documentation for the Heroku platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#authentication)  states that it can be accessed with basic HTTP authentication using the API token, as follows:

> HTTP basic authentication must be constructed from email address and
>   api token as {email-address}:{token}, base64 encoded and passed as the
>   Authorization header for each request, for example Authorization:
>   Basic 0123456789ABCDEF=.

We have tried this but keep on getting an "Invalid credentials provided" error.

However, if we substitute our Heroku account password for the token, authentication works:

e.g. {email-address}:{password}, base64 encoded.

However, we don't want to have to use our password for API authentication. How do we get this working using the API token as described?

Comment: I should add that I can use the token provided by `heroku auth:token`for making API requests from my computer, but not from inside my Heroku app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look again at the [same documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#authentication) you linked to (it [has](http://web.archive.org/web/20140709223442/https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#authentication) changed in the meantime).

You should use `Authorization: Bearer HEROKU_TOKEN`, not `Authorization: Basic HEROKU_TOKEN` as you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to test this out later. Can you reference any documentation on this?

Comment: The link you had referenced in the question itself, @Yarin.